# ng-bind-html change my DOM structure

Tags: angularjs, templates

I've got the following code into my view template:

```
<div ng-bind-html="smthg" ></div>
```

My controller defines:

```
$scope.smthg= '<a href="#create"><div class="ui ...">Importer</div></a>';
```

But my browser got:

```
<div ng-bind-html="smthg">
    <a href="#create"></a>
    <div class="ui ...">Importer</div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 1.2.x AngularJS, I think you must use $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.smthg) to deal it.
Look at documentation for $sce

Comment: It's more like: `$scope.smthg = $sce.trustAsHtml('myHtmlCode')` isn't it? Is there a way to globaly disable sanitizing output?

Comment: not global, only your 'myHtmlCode', you can try it.